# Integrating existing web application with Azure AD for SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, saml, adfs, ws-federation

I am newbie in Azure AD field and little bit confused when I compare Azure AD vs ADFS from SSO perspective.

I have built a web site and integrated it with on premise ADFS for single sign on. I have used WS-Federation for this integration. User logs-in into the web application, the web application redirects the user to ADFS with SAMLRequest, user is authenticated against the ADFS and then ADFS sends the SAMLReesponse back to the web application. The web application verifies the response and retrieves the identify from the claims.

Now, I want to integrate same web application against Azure AD. My understanding is that the above solution should work as is with Azure AD. The only difference is change of the end point to which web application redirects the user.  The format of SAMLRequest and the SAMLResponse will be same in case of ADFS and Azure AD. Is my understanding correct, that from a developer’s perspective the way web application integrates with ADFS is same as how it integrates with Azure Ad?

My second question is about LDAP. Currently my application has another integration option. It directly connects with AD with LDAP, sends the credentials and AD authenticates the user.  Will my application directly able to connect to Azure AD over LDAP, the way I connect to AD with LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using WS-Fed but SAMLRequest and SAMLResponse are SAML 2.0.

Irrespective, yes it should work when you change the endpoint, the metadata address etc.

The way it integrates with both is the same.

Sorry, what do you mean by "connects with AD with LDAP". Is this on-premises AD? Where does LDAP fit in?

**Update**

You mean you are communicating with AD using the LDAP protocol rather than having an actual LDAP repository?

So the question is can Azure AD authenticate with on premises AD?

Yes - you can use a federated tenant (with ADFS for SSO) or use pass-through as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-pass-through-authentication).

Comment: There is another workflow, which accepts the AD credentials from the user and authenticates user using LDAP. so the application directly connects with AD to authenticate the user. This happens over secured VPN tunnel established between the web application and client's AD. I was just wondering, with Azure AD is it possible to authenticate user with LDAP the way it's working with on-premises AD.